# after adding a tag li float is not working

Tags: html, css

I want to create a horizontal navigation bar within the header. I use float: left for li tag and it was working fine. But after adding a tag before the li tag the li elements are not floating anymore. I can't understand where the problem is. Can anyone help me to fix this problem?

```css
body {
background-color:black}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}

#container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: arial;
}

header {
  background: url(images/header_image.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

#left_header {
  padding: 50px 0;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#right_header {
  float: right;
}

#right_header a {
  color: white;
}

#right_header ul {}

#right_header ul li {
  float: left;
  padding: 57px 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 2px;
  transition: background 1s;
}

#right_header ul li:hover {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <div id="left_header">
        <h1>The Real Estate</h1>
      </div>
      <nav id="right_header">
        <ul>
          <a href="#">
            <li>Home</li>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <li>Gallery</li>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <li>Our Works</li>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <li>Our Services</li>
          </a>
          <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </header>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Stay away from floats, at least to achieve this, if you want to keep sane. There a better and simpler ways to do that, I would suggest searching for "inline-block" for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using flex to do it because it makes it easier and you do not have to do clearfix every time and you should do inline block i li.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: arial;
}
    header {
        background: url(images/header_image.jpg);
        width: 100%;
        color: black;
    }
    nav {
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    }
        #left_header {
            padding: 50px 0;
            margin-left: 30px;
        }
        #right_header a {
            color: white;
        }
        #right_header ul {}
        #right_header ul li {
            padding: 57px 30px;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight: bold;
            list-style: none;
            margin: 0 2px;
            transition: background 1s;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        #right_header ul li:hover {
            background: orange;
        }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
          <nav id="right_header">
            <div id="left_header">
                <h1>The Real Estate</h1>
            </div>
                <ul>
                    <a href="#"><li>Home</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Gallery</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Our Works</li></a>
                    <a href="#"><li>Our Services</li></a>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @romjan mark it as correct answer so that other people can know that is the correct answer and learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

try this way ;)

```css
#right_header a {
  color: white;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: after use display: inline-block; the Home button gone to the very right.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

, i think the problem is the floating Li I usually use display: inline-block in the list items

I send you an example

```
   #right_header ul li {
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 57px 30px;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0 2px;
      transition: background 1s;
  }
```

https://codepen.io/r0binxp/pen/ZEWWvmj?editors=1100

The new element, need to display inline-block too, for taking space in the same line of the menu